# python cv2.circle sub-pixel drawing

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Does anyone know how to use cv2.circle with the sub-pixel "shift" parameter?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

i1 = np.zeros((256, 256, 3), np.float32)
cv2.circle(i1, (199,199), 10, (1,0,0), -1)
cv2.imshow('1', i1)
i2 = np.zeros((256, 256, 3), np.float32)
cv2.circle(i2, (199,199), 10, (1,0,0), -1, shift=1)
cv2.imshow('2', i2)

cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

I would expect the circle in the second circle to be at (99.5,99.5), 199*(2^-1) = 99.5
For me it appears in the same place as the first.
Cheers,

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The shift parameter is like working with everything multiplied by (1 << shift)
Thus if you want to draw a circle at (199.5, 199.5) you need to do something like this:

```
i2 = np.zeros((256, 256, 3), np.float32)
shift = 3
factor = (1 << shift)
cv2.circle(i2, (int(199.5 * factor + 0.5),int(199.5 * factor + 0.5)), 10 * factor, (1,0,0), -1, shift=shift)
cv2.imshow('2', i2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not encounter this issue as of today (openCV 3.1.0). However you have to be carefull: The input `radius` is shifted as well! Thus in your example the 2nd circle is half the size.